# create toolbar with my bitmap images

Tags: winapi, bitmap, toolbar

this is an example code of msdn to create toolbar, but this example use the standard images of the system.
What do I need to change in this code to use my images from resource file, for example: `IDB_COPY BITMAP "copy.bmp"`, and `IDB_CUT BITMAP "cut.bmp"`, and `IDB_PASTE BITMAP "paste.bmp"`.

```
HIMAGELIST g_hImageList = NULL;

HWND CreateSimpleToolbar(HWND hWndParent)
{
    // Declare and initialize local constants.
    const int ImageListID    = 0;
    const int numButtons     = 3;
    const int bitmapSize     = 16;

    const DWORD buttonStyles = BTNS_AUTOSIZE;

    // Create the toolbar.
    HWND hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, 
                                  WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                  hWndParent, NULL, g_hInst, NULL);

    if (hWndToolbar == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Create the image list.
    g_hImageList = ImageList_Create(bitmapSize, bitmapSize,   // Dimensions of individual bitmaps.
                                ILC_COLOR16 | ILC_MASK,   // Ensures transparent background.
                                numButtons, 0);

    // Set the image list.
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, 
            (WPARAM)ImageListID, 
            (LPARAM)g_hImageList);

    // Load the button images.
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_LOADIMAGES, 
            (WPARAM)IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR, 
            (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL);

    // Initialize button info.
    // IDM_NEW, IDM_OPEN, and IDM_SAVE are application-defined command constants.

    TBBUTTON tbButtons[numButtons] = 
    {
        { MAKELONG(STD_FILENEW,  ImageListID), IDM_NEW,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"New" },
        { MAKELONG(STD_FILEOPEN, ImageListID), IDM_OPEN, TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Open"},
        { MAKELONG(STD_FILESAVE, ImageListID), IDM_SAVE, 0,               buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"Save"}
    };

    // Add buttons.
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS,       (WPARAM)numButtons,       (LPARAM)&tbButtons);

    // Resize the toolbar, and then show it.
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0); 
    ShowWindow(hWndToolbar,  TRUE);

    return hWndToolbar;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
const int ID_TB_STANDARD = 0;

const int ID_IL_STANDARD = 0;

HWND hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, 
            WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_TB_STANDARD, hInstance, NULL);

HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_CUT), 16, 0, RGB(255, 0, 255));
ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_COPY)), NULL);
ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PASTE)), NULL);

SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)ID_IL_STANDARD, (LPARAM)hImageList);
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, (UINT) TB_SETHOTIMAGELIST, 0, (LPARAM)hHotImageList);
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

TBBUTTON tbb[3] = 
{
    {0,ID_CUT,TBSTATE_ENABLED,TBSTYLE_BUTTON},
    {1,ID_COPY,TBSTATE_ENABLED,TBSTYLE_BUTTON},
    {2,ID_PASTE,TBSTATE_ENABLED,TBSTYLE_BUTTON},
};



SendMessage(hWndToolbar, (UINT) TB_ADDBUTTONS, 3, (LPARAM)&tbb);

SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
ShowWindow(hWndToolbar , SW_SHOW);
```